# Negate or Not Condition-Element for MultiTrigger

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, triggers, conditional-statements

I´m currently learning WPF and the use of MultiTrigger and Conditions to set some properties of the styled control. I know that the Conditions of an MultiTrigger must all met (AND-Operator) to set the value specified by the Setter.

But does there exists a Condition if the value is not met (Lets name it a NotCondition). I have a small example to illustrate what i mean.

The Background-Property should be set to *'Red'* if the *mouse is over* the control and the content is *'Hello World'*.
The other case is, if the *mouse is over* and the content is **not** *'Hello World'*, the background should be *'Blue'*.

```
 <MultiTrigger>
   <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
     <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
     <Condition Property="Content" Value="Hello World" />
   </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
 </MultiTrigger>
 <MultiTrigger>
   <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
     <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
     <!--<NotCondition Property="Content" Value="Hello World" />-->
   </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
 </MultiTrigger>
```

How can i archive something like this in WPF/XAML? Is there a NotCondition-Element or an Attribute on the Condition-Element to negate the compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case with colors you can use triggers precedence. E.g.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Trigger>
<MultiTrigger>
 <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
  <Condition Property="Text" Value="Hello world"/>
 </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Latest trigger overrides effect from the first trigger when both mouse is over and text is *Hello world*.

There is nothing build-in in WPF that lets you do conditional triggers, **but** Mike Hillberg has suggested one very interseting solution for this problem: [A Comparable DataTrigger](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2008/09/30/ComparableDataTrigger.aspx)

Hope this helps